# Displaying ODG files thumbnails in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, images

I would like to manage network diagrams in a **Mediawiki** instance using **Libreoffice Draw (odg extension)** : importing the odg files in the wiki is working but it's actually impossible **to display thumbnails** of the files in pages.

Is there any way to do that? I didn't find any Mediawiki extension able to manage that kind of extension.

Comment: `*/5 * * * * php /var/www/html/maintenance/runJob.php --quiet --nothrottle --procs 8`
`@monthly php /var/www/html/maintenance/update.php --quiet`
`@weekly php /var/www/html/maintenance/updateSpecialPages.php  --quiet` i run this cronjobs that my thumbnails and other actions will be done, the first cronjob is the important one. remind, that /var/www/html/ is the wiki root dir.

Comment: thanks but it's not a question about thumbnails maintenance, it's more :  "how to manage thumbnails from .odg files".

Comment: then ask more  clearly specific?! :)

Comment: however, in case if thumbnails not shown or builded, you could also run rebuildImages.php

Comment: yep i updated the question, mediawiki handle common image thumbnails formats out of the box (png, jpeg, svg...) : odg files can be exported to image formats but that need to be done manually after each modification of the file... i'm looking for a solution to handle this conversion via mediawiki when the file is used.